# what is the default grafana setting for $__rate_interval

Tags: grafana

I understand that `rate(xyz[5m]) * 60` is the rate of xyz per minute, averaged over 5 mins.

1. How then would `$__rate_interval` and `$__interval` be defined,
   possibly in the same syntax?
2. What format is rate being measured here, in my panel? Per minute, per second?
3. What is the interval= 30s in my panel here? My scraping interval is set to 5s.[image: my dash board]
4. How do i change the rate format?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. See [New in Grafana 7.2: $__rate_interval for Prometheus rate queries that just work](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/09/28/new-in-grafana-7.2-__rate_interval-for-prometheus-rate-queries-that-just-work/).
2. Rate is always per second. See [Prometheus documentation for the rate function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate).
3. Click on Query options, then click on the Info-Symbol. An explanation will be displayed.
4. To get rate per minute, just multiply the rate with 60.

**Edit:** (`$__rate_interval` and `$__interval`)

Prometheus periodically fetches data from your application. Grafana periodically fetches Data from Prometheus. Grafana does not know, how often Prometheus polls your application for data. Grafana will estimate this time by looking at the configuration and assuming that every scrape gives us one data point. The `$__interval` variable then expands to the duration between two data points in the graph (Note that this is only true for small time ranges and high resolution as the intended use case for `$__interval` is reducing the number of data points when the time range is wide. See [Approximate Calculation of $__interval](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#__interval).)

If the time-distance between every two data points in each series is 15 seconds, it does not make sense to use anything less than `[15s]` as interval in the rate function. The rate function works best with at least 4 data points. Therefore `[1m]` would be much better than anything betweeen `[15s]` and `[1m]`. This is what `$__rate_interval` tries to achieve: guessing a minimal sensible interval for the rate function.

Personally, I think, this does not always work if your application delivers sparse data (less than one data point per scrape). I prefer using fixed intervals like 10m or even 1h or 1d in these situations. The interval need to be great enough to get you enough data points for the metric to work with the rate function.

A different approach would be to use any of `$__rate_interval` and `$__interval` but also set the *Min step* parameter for the query in the Grafana UI to be big enough.

Comment: Went through the documentation, but still have difficulty understanding $__rate_interval and $_interval. An explanation in laymen terms would be very appreciated.